# I want click and drag cursor to draw in grid using vue

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vue.js, path-finding

i want to create something like [pathfinding](https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/) using vue. So when i click and drag in the grid i want to get all the data-x and data-y value in array and change the color of those cells,
and when i click on obstacle button then it should draw accordingly.
i can use python for backend if that helps somehow .

here's my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <style>
      .g-x {
        width: max-content;
        display: flex;
      }
      .g-y {
        border: 1px solid #d8d6de;
        margin: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 24px 0 rgb(34 41 47 / 10%);
      }
      #grid {
        box-shadow: 0 4px 24px 0 rgb(34 41 47 / 10%);
      }
      span.inner-grid {
        width: 20px;
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        background-color: rgb(233, 166, 166);
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 3px;
      }
      span.inner-grid:hover {
        background-color: rgb(189, 224, 65);
      }
      .start {
        background-color: green;
      }
      .end {
        background-color: red;
      }

      .wall {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="">
      <div id="buttons" class="row">
        <div class="col-4 my-5 text-center btn-parent">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm setVal"
            v-on:click="setMode('start')"
            type="button"
          >
            Select Start
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 my-5 text-center btn-parent">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm setVal"
            v-on:click="setMode('end')"
            type="button"
          >
            Select End
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 my-5 text-center btn-parent">
          <button
            class="btn btn-primary btn-sm setVal"
            v-on:click="setMode('wall')"
            type="button"
          >
            Select Obstacle
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div id="grid" class="col-12">
          <span class="g-x" v-for="(x, index) in grid_x">
            <span class="g-y" v-for="(y, index) in grid_y">
              <span
                v-on:click="setVal()"
                :data-x="x"
                :data-y="y"
                class="inner-grid"
              >
              </span>
            </span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script>
      var grid_x = [];
      var grid_y = [];

      var mode = "start";

      for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        grid_x.push(i);
        grid_y.push(i);
      }

      var example2 = new Vue({
        el: "#grid",
        data: {
          parentMessage: "Parent",
          grid_x: grid_x,
          grid_y: grid_y,
        },
        methods: {
          setVal: function () {
            var element = event.target;
            var x = element.getAttribute("data-x");
            var y = element.getAttribute("data-y");
          },
        },
      });
      var button = new Vue({
        el: "#buttons",
        methods: {
          setMode: function (type) {
            mode = type;
          },
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In order to get responses here, clarify what your question is: what's working, and what's not? Rather than posting your entire code, post a minimal, reproducible, example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: My high-level advice here would be to store the grid as 2d array of objects so you can set properties such as blocking, searched, and color appropriately. Make sure you update the array appropriately so it is reactive (see: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html?redirect=true#For-Arrays). Also, you can use `@mouseover` and `@mousedown` for dragging, just check the event that is passed to the function to make sure the mouse button is pressed.